# Java Generics optimization needed

Tags: java, android, generics

I know it is complex, but can someone explain why is this error happening and what could I do about it.

> Type parameter 'MainFragment' is not within its bound; should extend AbsFragmentBase

given this inheritance chain:

```
public class BarcodeActivity extends
        AbsFullScreenMainActivityBase<CurrentBase, Settings, Callbacks, MainFragment>
        implements Callbacks { .... } 
          !
          !
public abstract class AbsFullScreenMainActivityBase<C extends CurrentBase, 
        S extends AbsSettingsBase, 
        L extends CallbacksBase<C, S>, 
        F extends AbsFragmentBase<L>>
        extends AbsMainActivityBase<C, S, L, F> 
        implements View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { .... }
          !
          !
public abstract class AbsMainActivityBase<C extends CurrentBase, 
        S extends AbsSettingsBase, 
        L extends CallbacksBase<C, S>, 
        F extends AbsFragmentBase<L>>
        extends AbsSimpleMainActivityBase<F> 
        implements CallbacksBase<C, S> { .... }                 
          !
          !
public abstract class AbsSimpleMainActivityBase<F extends Fragment>
        extends AppCompatActivity { .... }                                  


public class MainFragment extends AbsWebHost<BarcodeActivity>
        implements View.OnClickListener, Camera.PreviewCallback { ... }
          !
          !
public abstract class AbsWebHost<A extends AppCompatActivity 
      & MinimumWebHostCallbacks<? extends CurrentBase, ? extends AbsSettingsBase>> 
      extends AbsFragmentBase<A> { .... }
          !
          !
public abstract class AbsFragmentBase<L extends
      CallbacksBase<? extends CurrentBase, ? extends AbsSettingsBase>>
      extends Fragment 
      implements View.OnClickListener { .... }


public interface Callbacks extends MinimumWebHostCallbacks<CurrentBase, Settings> { .... }
          !
          !
public interface MinimumWebHostCallbacks<C extends CurrentBase, 
      S extends AbsSettingsBase> 
      extends CallbacksBase<C, S> { .... }
          !
          !        
public interface CallbacksBase<C extends CurrentBase, S extends AbsSettingsBase> { .... }



public class Settings extends AbsSettingsBase { .... }
```

The compilation succeeds, if I make these changes

```
public class MainFragment extends AbsWebHost<BarcodeActivity, Callbacks>
            implements View.OnClickListener, Camera.PreviewCallback { ... }
              |
              |
public abstract class AbsWebHost<A extends AppCompatActivity, 
          L extends MinimumWebHostCallbacks<? extends CurrentBase, ? extends AbsSettingsBase>> 
          extends AbsFragmentBase<L> { .... }
              |
              |
```

but I would prefer AbsWebHost<> to have only one parameterized type, since BarcodeActivity implements the interface needed

Thank you

Comment: Is this your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I was just wondering if you had done the effort to minimize; I’ll take yes for an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You see there are 11 classes in there. But it is as concise as it could be, for someone with the proper knowledge to give me a direction.